# Ionic 3 side menu close on button click

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am showing some categories in side menu which is working fine . but i need when i click on category then the category show . and it also work fine . but the problem is when i click on category it shows the category but closes the menu . (so if i need to see the category im opening the sidemenu again . i dont want to close the side menu ) .

```
  <div class="list-item-divider" (click)="onButtonClick()">
     <ion-item-divider tappable menuClose (click)="shop()">
      <ion-icon item-left ios="ios-home" md="md-home">
      </ion-icon>
      <strong>{{"Categories" | translate}}
      </strong>
    </ion-item-divider>
  </div>        

 <div *ngIf="buttonClicked" >
  <div *ngIf="service.categories" class="category-name">
    <ion-item tappable full menuClose *ngFor="let item of 
       service.mainCategories" (click)="getCategory(item.id, item.slug, 
        item.name)">
      <ion-icon item-right class="ion-ios-arrow-forward item-icon">
      </ion-icon>
      <span [innerHTML]="item.name"></span>     
    </ion-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts

```
   public buttonClicked: boolean = false;

     public onButtonClick() {
      this.buttonClicked = !this.buttonClicked;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly, you do not need to close sidemenu when you tap on any of the links within

then you need to remove the `menuClose` there.

Comment: yes when i dont need to close menu on click category .

Comment: May i ask why i was down voted?. Removing menuClose will keep the sidemenu open even when tapped.

Comment: your answer is right i use menuClose thats why its closing the side menu. dont know why someone downvote your answer.